# Add new row in existing table

Tags: javascript, model, sapui5

I want to add new row with existing table.

my code:

```js
onInit: function() {
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("Model/Clothing.json");
    this.getView().setModel(oModel);
    var table = this.getView().byId("tableid");
    table.bindItems("/catalog/clothing/categories", new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
      type: "Navigation",
      press: function(evt) {},
      cells: [
        new sap.m.Text({
          text: "{name}"
        }), new sap.m.Text({
          text: "{amount}"
        }), new sap.m.Text({
          text: "{currency}"
        }), new sap.m.Text({
          text: "{size}"
        })
      ]
    }));
    table.setModel(oModel);
  },
  onPress: function(oEvent) {
    var table = this.getView().byId("tableid");
    var items = table.getSelectedItems();
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      var data = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
        cells: [new sap.m.Text({
          text: "new Row1"
        }), new sap.m.Text({
          text: "new row1"
        }), new sap.m.Text({
          text: "new row1"
        }), new sap.m.Text({
          text: "new row1"
        })]
      });
      table.addItem(data);
    }
  },
```

```html
<Table id="tableid" mode="MultiSelect" select="addRows">
  <columns>
    <Column>
      <Text text="column1" />
    </Column>
    <Column>
      <Text text="column2" />
    </Column>
    <Column>
      <Text text="column3" />
    </Column>
    <Column>
      <Text text="column4" />
    </Column>
  </columns>
</Table>
<Button text="Edit" press="onPress" />
```

Here is my output image

[image: Table]

Now exactly what I want to achieve,

1. I select any checkbox.
2. Then I will press on `Edit` button.
3. Now on press `Edit` button `I want to add one more row below selected checkbox row.`

So can I achieve this.

**Note** *right now the new row is adding at last in the table*

Answer (score 1):

Use [`insertItem`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html#insertItem) to insert item at specified index.

It takes two arguments viz. item to be added and index at which it is to be added.

So, first get index of item under which you want to add item with [`indexOfItem`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html#indexOfItem) then use that index `+1` as index for new item.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/divata/edit?html,js,output) is demo.

Comment: Thank @Dopedev, but if I select all three row and press on edit button then new row will be add below each selected rows..

Comment: right now its adding at index 0 only..so how can I do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you use data binding, you should **definitely not** add a new table row control -- instead, add a new entry to your model node:

EDIT: updated my answer:

```
onPress : function(oEvent) {
    var oModel   = this.getView().getModel();                               // the model
    var aRows    = oModel.getProperty("/catalog/clothing/categories");      // array with all rows in the model
    var oThisObj = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext().getObject();      // the current object
    var item     = { name: null, amount: null, currency: null, size: null } // an empty object

    var index = $.map(aRows, function(obj, index) {                         // get the index of the selected item in your array
        if(obj === oThisObj) {
            return index;
        }
    })

    aRows.splice(index, 0, item);                                           // add the item at the index

    oModel.setProperty("/catalog/clothing/categories", aRows);              // store the array back to the model
}
```

Comment: I tired but not getting...@Qualiture can u share demo..Thanks

Comment: It is just simple Javascript really.... see my updated answer